# Why does the span not appear?

Tags: html, css

This is a css

```
#loading {
        margin: 80px auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
           -moz-border-radius: 50px;
                border-radius: 50px;
        background: #ccc;
        font: 12px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        color: white;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    }
    #loading:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
          left: -20px;
           top: -20px;
        bottom: -20px;
         right: -20px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
           -moz-border-radius: 70px;
                border-radius: 70px;
        background: #eee;
        z-index: -2;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    #loading span {
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 50px solid transparent;
        border-right: 50px solid transparent;
        border-top: 80px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        z-index: -1;
        top: -28px;
        left: 0px;
        -webkit-animation: ticktock 5s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: ticktock 5s linear infinite;
        animation:ticktock 5s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50px 80px;
        -moz-transform-origin: 50px 80px;
        transform-origin:50px 80px;
    }
    #loading strong {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        -webkit-animation: expand 2.5s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: expand 2.5s linear infinite;
        animation:expand 2.5s linear infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes expand {
        0% {
                width: 0;
        }
        100% {
                width: 60px;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes ticktock {
        0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                -ms-transform: rotate(0);
                 transform: rotate(0);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        }
        100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
                 transform: rotate(360deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes expand {
        0% {
                width: 0;
        }
        100% {
                width: 60px;
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes ticktock {
        0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                -ms-transform: rotate(0);
                 transform: rotate(0);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        }
        100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
                 transform: rotate(360deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }



    @keyframes ticktock {
        0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                -ms-transform: rotate(0);
                 transform: rotate(0);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0);
        }
        100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
                 transform:rotate(360deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }


    @keyframes expand {
        0% {
                width: 0;
        }
        100% {
                width: 60px;
        }
    }
```

this is the html

```
<div id="loading"><strong>loading...</strong><span></span></div>
```

The problem that this is the result
http://jsfiddle.net/jtrax/

**It is working good and the circle is rotating**

But when I add a completely separate css the circle is disappear, this is a jfiddle after adding the css **which is not related to the circle**

http://jsfiddle.net/HSJ3j/

Before adding the unrelated css:

[image]

After adding the unrelated css:

[image]

#### I forgot to tell you that the wrong is happening in the span in the html

#### Edit

when I change the z of loading span to 1 and the z of #loading:before to 0, I got this result
[image]

Comment: So then what's in the unrelated css? It must be related in some ways since it is affecting your circle

Comment: That’s because you first `fieldset` element is laying on top of the moving circle … which is quite easy to find out using your browser’s inspector tools.

Comment: @Huangism yes but I tried to figure out what is making it related but I couldn't , that is why I asked here

Comment: @CBroe I don't know but I tried to debug it through f12 and the`loading` section is too wide, so there is nothing above it

Comment: You should be able to slide your z indexes up so that everything shows up how you want it to.

Comment: The `fieldset` _is_ above it – remove its white background color if you don’t believe it.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli since your loading div z-index is -2, the `fieldset` is on top of your loading div. If you set z-index of `fieldset` to -3, then it will work, or if you remove background colour for fieldset it will also work

Comment: @CBroe yes you right, it is above it. how to fix that please? i tried to give the z to 1, and the z of the loading content to 2, but nothing change

Comment: @Huangism you right, but even when I make the z of the span to 1 and the z of the loading content to 2, then I didn't get the result that I expect to get whenI showed u the image

Comment: Simply adding `z-index:0` for `#msform fieldset` should fix it (depending on what else you are planning to do with that fieldset, of course). Recommended read: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: @CBroe can we fix that on the css of the loading not the css of the other part please? I edited the quesiton could you check please?

Comment: @Huangism I edited the question could you check please

Comment: I feel like this could of been much easier if you just restructured the loading div stacking order

Comment: @Huangism yes exactly that is what I am thinking in, that is why I tried to change the z of them and I edited the question to show you the result, could you check please

Comment: @Huangism help please

Answer (score 1):

I restructured your loading div so it makes more sense and easier to understand

http://jsfiddle.net/jtrax/1/

```
<div id="loading">
    <span></span>
    <div class="inner"><strong>loading...</strong></div>
</div>
```

You can check the css in the fiddle. The spinning span might need more adjustment to centre it but you get the idea

UPDATED fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HSJ3j/3/

If you look at the stacking order, the loading text should be the highest, then the grey smaller circle, then the spinning span and finally the outer bigger circle. Construct your div according to that and it makes things much easier

Comment: you gave me the jfiddle without the "unrelated" css (which is related) , the problem happens when the two css is together, however, I will try you code in my machine and update u

Comment: your code have a big problem when I added it to the previous css, the circle is appear, but the rotating cirlce is rotating in a different location, it is not working in this way

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli you just need to add `position: relative;` to loading div and centre the span. See my second fiddle in the updated answer

Comment: please check your new jfiddle please, the cicle is rotating in a very strange thing(sorry my english is not good to describe it )please just look at it for 10 second and u will notice

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli as I mentioned before, you NEED to CENTER it

Comment: I am trying to do that, but no success until now, I will tell you if I couldn't do that.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli you just need to make sure the shape, border, top and left are correct and it should look the same as before

Comment: First, I would rather use `before` instead of `inner` class. second, I would prefer playing with the z to make it better, Thsu, I applied your new `z` value to my previous code  but nothing change, I really appreciate if you could help me with that. that is my question, just chaging the z (nothing with html or new css). please

Comment: my code was already working, so I don't need a new html and new css code because I already make it work the new code makes me change my diagram and tell my working ground that I did that

Comment: if it is just a matter of z values, why we need to change more things ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli it does not work with `:before` but feel free to keep trying. I have updated my question with the span spinning from the center.

Comment: I tried a lot but no success :( :( even your new updated jfiddle is not working good, please check it again :( i am gonna loose my mind in this thing

Comment: check your new jfiddle please ,the same problem, the circle is not rotating well, it is like triangle rotating not cirlce rotating

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli it's always been a triangle rotating, same as your working on without the form. You don't see it because the background colour is the same as the triangle. Move the loading to an area where it won't overlap anything

Answer (score 0):

It's just an arrangement issue.

Your `fieldset` tag is over your animation. Try to arrange your `fieldset` to be styled with `z-index:-1;`.